Unreasonable boot time in Pop OS 22.04
I saw a similar post here about a prior version of pop os [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699557/diagnosing-absurdly-long-boot-time-on-pop-os-21-10] but my system log isn't the same and as I'm a linux newbie I can't quite know what is happening here. I'm pastin here what I think are the critical parts for the dmesg command and also the lsblk for more info on the system.
[    9.893625] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[   10.050066] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): mounted filesystem d2123aa3-4f71-4a56-ad6b-371e58231ac2 ro with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   42.208276] nvme nvme0: I/O tag 448 (61c0) opcode 0x2 (I/O Cmd) QID 8 timeout, aborting req_op:READ(0) size:131072
[   42.208288] nvme nvme0: I/O tag 450 (41c2) opcode 0x2 (I/O Cmd) QID 8 timeout, aborting req_op:READ(0) size:131072
[   72.928276] nvme nvme0: I/O tag 448 (61c0) opcode 0x2 (I/O Cmd) QID 8 timeout, reset controller
[   72.960517] nvme0n1: I/O Cmd(0x2) @ LBA 793087840, 256 blocks, I/O Error (sct 0x3 / sc 0x71) 
[   72.960522] I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 793087840 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   72.960529] nvme0n1: I/O Cmd(0x2) @ LBA 793088096, 256 blocks, I/O Error (sct 0x3 / sc 0x71) 
[   72.960532] I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 793088096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   72.960542] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
[   72.960544] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
[   73.046449] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
[   73.110695] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues

NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda             8:0    0 894.3G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0   450M  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0   100M  0 part  
├─sda3          8:3    0    16M  0 part  
├─sda4          8:4    0 102.8G  0 part  
├─sda5          8:5    0   249M  0 part  
├─sda6          8:6    0   553M  0 part  
└─sda7          8:7    0 789.6G  0 part  
zram0         251:0    0  15.5G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1       259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  1022M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0     4G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0 467.9G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p4   259:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 252:0    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]


I have windows on a sata ssd and Pop Os on a nvme disk. I have to stay like 1:30 minutes in the grey screen before the login and I have tried to clean install a couple of times. It seems it has something to do with the nvme disk but I have no idea how to fix this.
Thanks!

That's a hardware problem: your nvme SSD doesn't respond to some "read this" commands in time. Some file isn't accessible due to that, possibly that's also the reason Linux decided to mount a file system read-only ("ro") above.

but I have no idea how to fix this.

Hardware fault – can only be fixed by replacing the SSD.

While not always 100% correct I would check drive with Smart Status. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools If you have gnome and then gnome-disks, it is in icon in upper right corner. Or install: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445397&p=13965854#post13965854

@oldfred I actually do have a Lexar SSD with the same problem as OP – the SMART equivalent for NVMe is clean as can be. So, don't put too much hopes into that.

@MarcusMüller I'm curious about how can everything seems fine in a health check but the disk fails in a real world scenario. Any idea what could be happening in these situations?

@Moltimor these health checks simply don't check the same things as whatever fails. No magic there – the firmware of the drive simply can't try to read everything in self-check, nor can it try all possible combinations of commands and controller firmware state when doing a test.

I'm just sharing my answer here, I had a similar issue, diagnosing it with sudo journalctl -b I could see my PopOS was trying to find the SWAP partition by its id, but it couldn't find it so it took a lot until a timeout is thrown, then the OS allow me to login.
To fix it:

I removed the line containing my swap entry in /etc/crypttab
Commented my swap entry in /etc/fstab
Removed cached swap references with sudo update-initramfs -u

Now it's fixed.
